# Getting client certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I need to implement Client Certificate authentication on some of the endpoints in my .NET 5 Web API. So I don't want to enable HTTPS across all endpoint as described [here in the MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0). I am using Kestrel on my local machine and not IIS express or IIS.

I have tried the following three methods with no luck on either of them:

```
var clientCertHeaders = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
```

This one returns the normal headers for the request but no certificate.

```
var clientCert = context.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
var clientCertAsync = context.HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync().Result;
```

These two both return null.

I've tried applying the following to my services:

```
services.AddCertificateForwarding(options =>
    {
        options.CertificateHeader = "X-SSL-CERT";
        options.HeaderConverter = (headerValue) =>
        {
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = null;

            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue))
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerValue);
                clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(bytes);
            }

            return clientCertificate;
        };
    });
```

Even with that enabled in my services I am not retrieving the client certificate.

I am using Postman to make the requests to the API requests.

Comment: On your link for IIS there are three options for SSL settings 1) Ignore 2) Accept 3) Require.  You can use option 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure Kestrel to allow client certificates in the `program.cs` The default value is `ClientCertificateMode.NoCertificate` so in your `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` you need to change that to `ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate`.

Here's an edited chunk of code from the docs you sent where I did that:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
            {
                o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o => 
                o.ClientCertificateMode = 
                ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate);
            });
        });
}
```